# iOS App - Change Version Number Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

Would it be possible (/Is it allowed) to release one App Update after another with the following different Version Number Schemes?

Release: 1.0.0
Adding new Feature: 1.1.0
Fixing a problem for a specific customer: 1.1.0.1
Adding new Feature: 1.2.0

So generally i'd like to switch between a Version Number Format of 3 and 4 parts and wanted to know if someone knows if this could be problematic with Apple or the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Apple cares the format of the version number.  I started with 1.0.0 then switched to 1.1 and then released 1.52.  As long as the version number is different it is fine.  Check out google chrome versions they always have weird version numbers

Comment: I honestly did not think about checking other apps version numbers -.-
I looked into it and found that the iOS Reeder App switched between a Version Number of 2 and 3 parts (http://www.appannie.com/app/ios/reeder/). So it seems to be okay to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple will let you switch between a Version Number Format of 3 and 4 parts as long as the versions are incremental.